# Spring Data CrudRepository custom ID generator

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, id-generation

I am using spring boot(1.4),spring data and jpa. And using `@Repository`(CrudRepository)
One of my Table/Entity, the ID  column, I want to generate customised string.
Start with some specific string plus creation data and time, and end with next value from db.
so here I can't use `@TableGenerator`, I need some native query like "select  nextvalue "

Is there better way can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "normal" ID column using `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` and then manually fill your special column after the entity has been stored the first time.